# Minecraft Error Occured. How do I stop this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

Sometimes, when I try to play Minecraft on a singleplayer or multiplayer world, it crashes. Here's the crash log:

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 307]
[14:53:18] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Rightenz
[14:53:20] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[14:53:21] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, Tiny Pixels - 25th October - Copy, PF.Resources, novaskin
[14:53:23] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[14:53:23] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[14:53:23] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[14:53:25] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[14:53:25] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[14:53:27] [Client thread/WARN]: Texture minecraft:textures/blocks/portal.png with size 8x8 limits mip level from 4 to 3
[14:53:27] [Client thread/WARN]: textures: dropping miplevel from 4 to 3, because of minimum power of two: 8
[14:53:27] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[14:53:49] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.10.2
[14:53:49] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[14:53:49] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[14:53:50] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[14:53:51] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 10%
[14:53:52] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 30%
[14:53:53] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 51%
[14:53:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 75%
[14:53:55] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 96%
[14:53:56] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 4, from 10
[14:53:57] [Server thread/INFO]: Rightenz[local:E:b3a537fb] logged in with entity id 1729 at (-167.2159220274755, 65.0, 113.5371539039923)
[14:53:57] [Server thread/INFO]: Rightenz joind teh gaem
[14:53:58] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving and pausing game...
[14:53:58] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'New Burld'/Overworld
[14:54:00] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'New Burld'/Nether
[14:54:00] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'New Burld'/The End
[14:54:03] [Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded? Running 5092ms behind, skipping 101 tick(s)

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x27204960, pid=4148, tid=4928
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x44960]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\VIC\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid4148.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Is there any way to fix this bug and continue the game without crashes?

Comment: Please note that arqade is not a bug-submission site. Mojang has an official bug tracker. As for your problem: make sure you are playing without mods, have the latest stable release of java 1.8 and a stable minecraft version installed. Try deleting `%appdata%\.minecraft` (backup the `saves` folder first, it contains your worlds. Also, make sure the worlds you play in weren't previously modded - this could corrupt them. If you have tried all those, please consider updating your question with more details, as it is very hard for us to determine your problem with this little information. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If the java runtime environment is crashing  (as opposed to the java program itself), it is usually the fault of native code (in this context, OpenGL). Try updating OpenGL drivers, java, and optifine. If you're using an unstable version of optifine, try switching to a stable version, or testing it with none at all. If you're allocating a custom amount of memory, try allocating more or less. This minecraftforum post might help you: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/modded-client-support/1952484-failed-to-write-core-dump

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you update your video drivers.

```
Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x44960]
```

The file referenced in this error is a OpenGL Driver. Specifically, it is related to Intel Graphics.
http://www.freefixer.com/library/file/ig4icd32.dll-75755/

You can download the dll file here:
https://www.dll-files.com/ig4icd32.dll.html.
Scroll down to "ADVANCED USER? GET THE DLL FILE AND INSTALL IT YOURSELF" and drag the dll file downloaded into your System32 folder.

Comment: NONONONO. A video driver isn't a single .dll file. They should update their video drivers via control panel or better yet, from the official website.